# Why does socket.inet_ntoa returns packed format in python

Tags: python, ip-address

Why does socket.inet_aton returns packed format in python?

If I am storing the IP as integer in Database (mysql), do I have to always extract the integer value or is there any easier way out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[inet_aton](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html?highlight=inet_aton#socket.inet_aton) is clearly documented to perform exactly this task, and the "why" is even very explicitly explained...:

> Convert an IPv4 address from
>   dotted-quad string format (for
>   example, ‘123.45.67.89’) to 32-bit
>   packed binary format, as a string four
>   characters in length. This is useful
>   when conversing with a program that
>   uses the standard C library and needs
>   objects of type struct `in_addr`, which
>   is the C type for the 32-bit packed
>   binary this function returns.

To convert from a 4-byte string to an integer and vice versa, see the [struct](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html?highlight=struct#module-struct) module.